# After Login and move to next page its automatically logout

Tags: php, jquery, session

I am working on a project on which there is a header which contain login link . There are two header on my project header.php and header1.php. header.php is included on index.php and header1.php is on rest of the page.

When I am going to my site www.example.com which contain header.php and login it show me that I am logged in but when I move to next page on the site it does not show me logged in and also when I move to home page(index.php) there also I am not logged in.

header.php :- on index.php

```
    <?php 
        @session_start();
        include_once('functions/config.php');
    ?>

// and some html code
```

header1.php :- rest of the page

```
    <?php
        //ob_start();
        @session_start();
        include("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/functions/config.php");
    ?>

// and some html code
```

vali.js (for validation) :-

```
$("#login_frm").validate({
   rules: {
       email: {
           required: true,
           email: true
       },
       pass: {
           required: true,
           minlength: 6
       },
   },
   messages: {
       pass: {
           required: "Please provide a password",
           minlength: "Your password must be at least 6 characters long"
       },
       email: "Please enter email adress"
   },
   submitHandler: function(form) {
       $.post('http://www.example.com/logincheck.php', $("#login_frm").serialize(), function(data) {
           if(data == '1') {
            document.location='http://www.example.com/';
           } else {
        $('#login-error').html('Wrong Username or password');
           }
       });              
    }
});
```

logincheck.php (session set):-

```
<?php
    include("functions/config.php");
    include("functions/encript.php");
    ob_start();
    session_start();

    $email = $_POST['email'];

    $pass= encode5t($_POST['pass']);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM members where email='$email' AND pass='$pass' AND member_status='1' ";
    //echo $sql;

    $row = mysql_query( $sql );
    $count = mysql_num_rows( $row );
    $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($row);
    if($count == 1) {
        $member_id = $result['member_id'];  
        $first_name = $result['first_name'];                                                                
        $creditamount = $result['credit'];
        $_SESSION['memid'] = $member_id;            
    $_SESSION['ufname'] = $first_name;      
        $_SESSION['uemail'] = $email;
        $_SESSION['creditamount'] = $creditamount;      
        //echo "->".$_SESSION['memid'];

        setcookie ("memid", $member_id, (time()+60*60*24*360)); 
        setcookie ("login2", "true", (time()+60*60*24*360));        
        setcookie ("uname", $first_name, (time()+60*60*24*360));
        setcookie ("uemail", $email, (time()+60*60*24*360));
        echo '1';//header("location:index.php");

    } else {
        echo "Wrong Username Or Password";
    }

?>
```

I dont know what is happening also this problem occurs for the first time when I am logged in for the second time it does not give me any problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: rename `@session_start();` to just `session_start();`. I think `@` is creating problem.

Comment: tried but facing same problem

Answer (score 3):

This problem may due to the reason below

The same variable name in header and in other files. The variable may be used in header

```
$_SESSION['userid']
```

The variable  **$userid**  is used in some other files may be. If you find that this issue will clear i think

Comment: $_SESSION['userid'] not $_SESSION['$userid'].

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `session_start();` at the top of every page using it.

Comment: but your `session_start()` does not stay on top at page `logincheck.php`

Comment: I dont think this will create problem , I also tried this but same problem